# How does one read aloud Vinogradov's notation $\ll$ and $\ll_{\epsilon }$?

Tags: number-theory, notation, analytic-number-theory, pronunciation

How does one read aloud the [Vinogradov's notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_.28Bachmann-Landau.2C_Hardy.2C_and_Vinogradov_notations.29) $\ll$ and $\ll_{\epsilon }$ as in

$$f(x)\ll g(x)$$

and

$$c\ll_{\epsilon }\left( \prod\limits_{p\mid abc}p\right) ^{1+\epsilon}.$$

Is the first one “is very much less than”? (This is a direct translation from Portuguese as was used  informally in engineering formulae).

*Added*: I am not asking the meaning of this notation, rather how it is read.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36365/752) answer to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36364/752) mentioned in Unreasonable Sin's comment points to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols) Wikipedia entry. According to it in Analytic number theory the symbol $\ll$ in $f(x)\ll g(x)$ is to be read as “is of smaller order than”.

*Added 2*.  As a response to LVK's comment:

> "I am not asking the meaning of this notation, rather how it is read."
>   But the way to spell out notation depends on what it means in the
>   particular text. If Vinogradov used it to mean $f=O(g)$ in one of his
>   papers, then in that paper the symbol should be read differently.

Let me give a specific example. I would like to know how to read $\ll _{\epsilon }$ in the following conjecture

> ABC Conjecture. *Suppose* $A,B,$ and $C$ *are positive integers, suppose*
>            $$\gcd (A,B,C)=1,$$
>            *and suppose* 
>            $$A+B=C.$$
>            *Then*
>            $$C\ll _{\epsilon }\left( \prod\limits_{p\mid ABC}p\right) ^{1+\epsilon}.$$

Source: *Arithmetic Algebraic Geometry*, Brian Conrad, Karl Rubin, ch. 5, p.123.

The meaning as I understand it is the same as:

*Suppose:*

i) $A,B$ *and* $C$ *are positive integers,*

ii) $\gcd (A,B,C)=1,$

iii) $A+B=C,$

iv) $\epsilon >0$ *is a positive real number*.

*Then there is a constant* $K_{\epsilon}$ *such that* 
$$C\leq K_{\epsilon}\left( \prod\limits_{p\mid ABC}p\right)^{1+\epsilon }.$$

P.S. The symbol $\ll_{\epsilon}$ is also used in Terence Tao's post [*The probabilistic heuristic justification of the ABC conjecture*](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/the-probabilistic-heuristic-justification-of-the-abc-conjecture/).

Comment: @PeterTamaroff It sounds better!

Comment: @Byron Schmuland Thanks for correcting the name in the title!

Comment: @AméricoTavares No problem. It is a small thing, but it bugged me.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Of course, because it is a name.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36364/what-does-ll-mean where the dual use of that notation is discussed.

Comment: @UnreasonableSin Thanks! So, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols), the symbol $\ll$ is to be read as "is of smaller order than". And what about $\ll_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @AméricoTavares: If I had to read $X \ll_{\epsilon} Y$, I would say "$X$ is much less than a constant depending on $\epsilon$ times $Y$".

Comment: @PeterTamaroff In the Wikipedia entry I linked to in the edit if $\ll$ were an inequality, which is not in the present case, it would be read as "is much less than".

Comment: "I am not asking the meaning of this notation, rather how it is read." But the way to spell out notation depends on what it means in the particular text. If Vinogradov used it to mean $f=O(g)$ in one of his papers, then in that paper the symbol should be read differently.

Comment: Someone didn't like my question as it is.

Comment: @LVK I edited the question in response to your comment.

Comment: It is not "very much less than". The symbol is about order.

Comment: @timur So, when we speak about the order of two functions $\ll$ is read  “is of smaller order than”. And what about $\ll_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: "controlled by a constant multiple of ..., with the constant possibly depending on epsilon", or if you just don't want to be quite as you write it on blackboard, "less less sub epsilon".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a default, I second Gerry Myerson's answer "less-than-less-than", although just reading "sub-epsilon" seems a little odd. In a situation where I'm trying to reinforce the meaning, I might read $A\ll B$ as "$A$ is dominated by $B$", and $A\ll_\varepsilon B$ as "$B$ dominates $A$ depending on $\epsilon$", but this may be defeating the purpose/intent of the question. (Edit: or, better, as noted by Americo Tavares, to say "$A$ is dominated by $B$ depending on $\varepsilon$", to avoid the need to read ahead...)

Comment: Thanks. This has nothing to do with the original question, but as for $A\ll_{\epsilon}B$ instead of "$B$ dominates $A$ depending on $\epsilon$" couldn't we say with the same meaning "$A$ is dominated by $B$ depending on $\epsilon$"?

Comment: @Americo... oh, yes, certainly the verb can be arranged so that the $A$, $B$ are spoken in the same order as appearing on the page. Probably preferable, yes, rather than seeming to require look-ahead.

Answer (score 3):

I read $\ll$ as "less than less than". I don't think I have ever put $\ll_{\epsilon}$ in words, but if I did it would probably come out "less than less than sub epsilon".

Comment: +1 Thanks! It appears e.g. in ch.5 of *Arithmetic Algebraic Geometry* by Brian Conrad, Karl Rubin. And in Terence Tao's [last post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/the-probabilistic-heuristic-justification-of-the-abc-conjecture/).

Comment: This is getting dangerously close to reading $X\simeq Y$ as "X-tilde-over-horizontal-line-Y".

Comment: @Américo, I didn't mean to suggest I hadn't ever seen the notation with the subscript, only that I have never had occasion to read it out loud to anyone.

Comment: @LVK, I've heard X~Y read "$X$ twiddles $Y$," though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks again for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

"Controlled by a constant multiple of ..., with the constant possibly depending on epsilon", or if you don't want to be quiet as you write it on blackboard, "less less sub epsilon".

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, for $\ll$ we say "Less than less than" and as for $\ll_\epsilon$, I would say "Less than less than where the constant depends on epsilon."

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Charles' answer in the thread I linked to, $f(x)\ll_{\epsilon} g(x)$ means that for a given $\epsilon$ there exists some $N$ and $k$ such that for all $x > N$, $f(x) < k\cdot g(x)$. In other words, $k$ and $N$ depend on the value of $\epsilon$. As to how you would read or pronounce that, I am not sure.

Comment: If you are unsure how to answer the question, why did you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to say " doubly less than ", which is more convenient than " less than less than " when speaking Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

I would say/I have heard it said "$A$ is (upper) bounded by $B$, (perhaps) up to a (big/small) constant factor (depending on ...)", or "we have a (lower/upper) bound of $A$ by $B$, [same as before]".