# What does the symbol $\lll$ mean?

Tags: notation

$A < B$ means $A$ is smaller than $B$.

$A \ll B$ means $A$ is some orders of magnitude smaller than $B$ (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36364/31408) for a more in-depth discussion). In modelling, it may mean that $A$ can be neglected ($A + B \approx B$).

In the [$\mathrm\LaTeX$  `amssymb` symbol list](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/amssymblist.pdf), section *Binary relations*, I found the symbols $\lll$ and $\ggg$, spelt as `\lll` and `\ggg`, respectively. What does $A \lll B$ mean? An order of magnitude of order of magnitudes smaller? Does it mean $A \cdot B \approx B$ even if $A \gg 1$? Like in this example?

$B=10^{10^{10}}$ and $A=10^{10}$, then $A \cdot B$ = $10^{10^{10}} \cdot 10^{10} \approx 10^{10^{10}+10} \approx 10^{10^{10}} \approx B$.

$\ldots$or does it mean something else?

Comment: Can you provide an example of its use?

Comment: If this symbol is actually used anywhere (I've never seen it), then certainly the author would have defined it previously.

Comment: I've never seen the symbol either (and I use the second symbol differently than you do). I suspect it was defined in whatever text you are reading. (edit: In other words, I agree with David Mitra)

Comment: I've found it in the LaTeX symbol list, and added a link in the question.

Comment: Taking into account your edit, it is almost certain that there is no commonly accepted meaning for that symbol.

Comment: It means "very much less than"; what *that* means depends on the situation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting [Mariano Suárez-Alvarez](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11495/notation-for-the-inclusion-map-is-a-homotopy-equivalence/11496#11496):

> The symbol denotes whatever the author tells you it will denote in his comments about notation, and there is a special place in hell for users of unexplained notation.

Comment: Good answer, but why is it Community Wiki?

Comment: @gerrit Because the answerer felt he/she didn't deserve rep points

Answer (score 3):

Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's comment gives the correct answer that the usage of $\lll$ or $\ggg$ is nonstandard and will have to be defined in-context, but it might be of interest that several sources use these symbols to denote [bitwise shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). See examples [here](http://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-387-23483-7_158), [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11042-010-0590-3), and [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11042-010-0652-6).

Comment: Java has a `>>>` operator, but does not have `<<<`.  In any case, I doubt that's the intended use in the OP's case, as `>>>` is not the same as `⋙`.  (Also, your links are behind a pay-wall - can you find any examples that are free to view?)